# Paperclip + S3: Migrating existing files from one :path format to another

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, migration, paperclip

I have a model with a `avatar` paperclip attach. It has now a plain standard path

```
has_attached_file :avatar,
  :path => "/:id-:style-:filename"
```

Which I need to move into an obfuscated one

```
has_attached_file :avatar,
  :path => "/:id-:hash.:extension"
  :hash_secret => 'asecuresecret'
```

Everything's working fine with new images, but how do I migrate the existing files stored in S3 to the new path format, ie rename them?

I'm using paperclip 2.7 and Rails 3.2

Thanks !!!

Comment: For those interested, moving from hash to non-hash is a little more interesting and the best method I've found is to create a new `has_attached_file` to make the migration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This rake task should do the trick. I tried it with aws-sdk 1.5.2 and ruby 1.9.3p194.

The `new_key` should map to your new paperclip path. Don't forget to set `:acl` according to your needs.

```
namespace :data do
  desc 'aws images migration'
  task :migrate_images do |t, args|
    s3 = AWS::S3.new(:access_key_id => 'XXX', :secret_access_key => 'XXX')
    bucket = s3.buckets['your-bucket-name']
    bucket.objects.each do |object|
      new_key = object.key.gsub(........)
      new_object = bucket.objects[new_key]
      object.copy_to new_object, {:acl => :public_read}
    end
  end
end
```

The original file should be deleted manually or using a similar task, once you are sure the new file is correct.

Comment: Tested with ``aws-sdk`` 1.26 and ruby 2.0. Thanks and sorry for the delay in the acceptance!

Answer (score 14):

If you want to work only with Paperclip and you are not worried about re-uploading I followed another approach.

Let's suppose you have the following:

```
class User
   has_attached_file :image, path: "/:old_path/:filename"
   ...
end
```

and you want to migrate to the new path: `"/:new_path/:filename"`

my suggestion is to create a `FakeUser` with the old path and change it in the User model.

```
class FakeUser
   self.table_name = :users
   has_attached_file :image, path: "/:old_path/:filename"
   ...
end

class User
   has_attached_file :image, path: "/:new_path/:filename"
   ...
end
```

You can now write the following migration:

```
FakeUser.find_each do |fake_user|
   User.find(fake_user.id).update(image: fake_user.image)
   fake_user.image.destroy
end
```

You can then delete the FakeUser model when the migration is finished.

By the way, this approach will work perfectly also to migrate from local filesystem to S3 or vice-versa.

Comment: this did work for me, I even could simplify it by inheriting the fake model from the real model

`class FakeUser < User`

Comment: Very good solution to migrate all your files! Better than the scripts that I have saw.

Answer (score 0):

I would write a rake task (or just a plain script if you prefer, to be run in the rails context). If you're using the aws-s3 gem, iterate over the instances of the model which you know they have the old path format or try writing some condition on the filename to match them, and the move one by one.

```
Model.find_in_batches(:batch_size => 500,
      :conditions => "avatar_filename like 'SOMETHING_MATCHING'") do |o|
  AWS::S3::S3Object.rename(old_path(o.avatar), o.avatar.url, 'BUCKET_NAME')
end
```

If you have already configured avatar with the new path definition, write a method that can build the old path based on the avatar properties.

You can read the aws-s3 gem docs [here](http://amazon.rubyforge.org/doc/) to see how to establish a connection to your S3 account.