# Paperclip change images path after upgrade to rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

i have a problem with paperclip (3.0.2) after upgrade to rails 3.2 (from 3.0.10).

Originally the path of one image was:

```
"http://localhost:3000/system/photos/94/small/AudiLogo.jpg?1335392139"
```

and after the upgrade this kind of images never show again!, but if i upload a new picture this will display fine on page, but the new path that use is:

```
"localhost:3000/system/products/photos/000/000/094/smal/AudiLogo.jpg?1335392139"
```

Whats happend in the upgrade ? There's any solution for convert the olds path to new ?

I try with "rake paperclip:refresh:missing_styles" but dosen't works.

The paperclip config section it's this.

```
has_attached_file :photo,
        :processors => lambda { |a|
                        if a.external?
                                [:thumbnail]
                        else
                                [:thumbnail,:watermark]
                        end
                        },
        :styles => {
                :slider => { :geometry => "350x312#", :format => :jpg, :watermark_path => "#{Rails.root}/public/images/watermark.png", :position => "NorthEast" },
                :small => "100x50>",
                :medium => "200>x200",
                :thumb => "100x100>",
                :big => { :geometry => "640x480>", :format => :jpg, :watermark_path => "#{Rails.root}/public/images/watermark.png" }
                },
        :default_url => "/images/noimage.png"
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the "smal" segment of the new uri a typo?

Comment: Did you upgrade paperclip as well or just Rails?

Comment: Can you post the section of the relevant model that deals with Paperclip options for the attachment?

Comment: Seems to me all it's missing is the protocol string at the start - can't you just add that yourself?

Answer (score 15):

I had the same problem. You can fix this by creating a file like **config/initializers/paperclip.rb** and put

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options.merge!(
    :path => ":rails_root/public/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:basename.:extension", 
    :url => "/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"
)
```

Comment: Is there any script to or rake task to move files from old location to new one?

Answer (score 3):

I just had a similar upgrade and routed around my problem this way:

```
  has_attached_file :image,
    :url => "/images/photos/:id/:basename_:style.:extension",
    :path => ":rails_root/public/images/photos/:id/:basename_:style.:extension",
```

Comment: As @heavysixersays, setting the :path option like this will force Paperclip to behave as it used to. I will try to check the reason for the error though

Comment: thanks! This is an option to force the path and i would work, but may exist a method to made de migration automatly i mean.

Comment: @jgiunta I don´t think there's a way to automatically migrate. You can read [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10251309/paperclip-s3-migrating-existing-files-from-one-path-format-to-another/10337918#10337918) regarding that

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the "small" vs "smal" difference between original and current path is a typo, the other obvious change is the addition of the two numeric segments after the "/photos/".

```
".../photos/000/000/094/smal/AudiLogo.jpg?1335392139"
```

I suspect this is coming from an id_partition being used for the path. Are you setting a different default path interpolation in some other place?

Looking at Paperclip's code I see the [id_partition method](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/lib/paperclip/interpolations.rb) that would be responsible for this but still have not found any documentation pointing in the direction of a change in the default behavior. I did't get to follow the code in the gem to determine if it is a bug or undocumented change.